# How to insert a javascript in a single Sphinx page?

Tags: javascript, python, python-sphinx

We have sphinx documentation with 1000+ files and a single theme. In only one page (.rst file) I need to insert a javascript code, like that:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
 alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

How could I do that? I tried a block and a directive so far.

Comment: Where you want to insert that script?

Comment: A file like this one: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot_wiki/master/copter/source/docs/ac2_followme.rst

Comment: The idea is to insert a simple script in a single file not in all pages through the theme.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your .rst file:

```
.. raw:: html

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
     alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
    </script>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```